# How to open all links in modal using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to be able to open all links on a page in a modal.

Below is an example:

```
<a href="http://google.com.au">Google AU</a>
<a href-"http://google.com">Google US</a>
<a href="https://www.google.co.jp>Google JP</a>
```

I want these links to open a Bootstrap Modal iFrame, loading the `href=` website into the modal. We have hundreds of links on the home page (all within our own domain) that are currently opening in a new tab when clicked, but instead we want to be able to open them into a modal, similar to how MaterializeCSS does it:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" id="rs1" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <iframe class="iframe-seamless" src="https://google.com.au" title="Google AU"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without coding in all the modal `<div id="unique">` these links would not work, so is it possible to use Javascript to automatically make all links on the page open into the modal?

Thanks

Comment: this post might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378720/bootstrap-3-with-remote-modal

Comment: Seems like its deprecated as of v3.3. I've tried playing with the jQuery load as well without a lot of luck. This also seems promising http://stackoverflow.com/a/34513876/422687 @KiranShakya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should create an empty modal, the content will be filled based on the link that is clicked. Following Javascript should help achieve this. I have not tested it but it should look something like this.

```
$('a').click(function() { 
   $('#myModal .modal-content').html('<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"></iframe>'); 
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```