# Open remote page as modal view in bootstrap

Tags: django, https, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I thought this is very simple think to do, but I can't found it on internet.

How could I open outside page ( like https://google.com/ ) as a modal view?

I **don't** want to:

- Open page in new tab
- Open page in new popup window like:

  onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','MyWindow',width=600,height=300)
- Open my own pre-prepared page as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503683/jquery-to-open-bootstrap-v3-modal-of-remote-url)

Is there a way to do this? It should be reight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://google.com"></iframe>
```